# improve postgres query perfromance on windows with billions of records, TB data size

Tags: postgresql

using Postgres 9.6, pgAdmin 4 (for running the queries) on Windows 10 64-bit with Intel Core i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 16GB RAM, 1 TB C drive HDD , 2 TB D drive HDD. Postgres data is stored in D drive

I'm using Postgres to process some dataset that I receive in csv format- the steps involved are as follows

1. **Create table schema** - 4 tables are created, one for each set of csv files with the same schema as per the fields in the input csv files
2. **Import CSVs to Postgres DB** - Import around 4 sets of 500 CSV files each of around 4 million rows into own tables - say `table01`, `table02`, `table03`, `table04` - I use a batch file to get the list of csv files in each set and use `psql -c "\copy ..` command to import them. This process takes around 30s per csv file to import - so altogether 1000 minutes or **~17hrs** . Each table has **~2bill** rows and around **350MB** per table.
3. **Create a subset of valid records and select relevant columns** - For each table in #2 above, create a new table (say `table01_valid`, `table02_valid`, `table03_valid`, `table04_valid`) which has a subset of columns and exclude some rows based on a criteria - after this operation the number of rows comes down to **~1.5bill** per table with each table **~200MB** in size - this operation takes **~20hrs** to execute for the 4 tables
4. **Select distinct records and merge** - in this step the distinct rows from each table is selected, merge them via `union all` and a final distinct rows from the merged records is selected - this is saved into a new table say `table_valid_distinct_1234` - the table size is **~450mill** rows and **~35GB** size - this operation takes **~12hrs**
5. **Run transformations on some columns** - in this step for each row, two columns are concatenated and selected as `id` field , two other columns are hashed, then concatenated and selected as `name` field. A final select is performed on this set to remove any `id`s with more than one unique `name` - the table size is **~50GB** with **~450mill** rows- this operation takes **~5hrs**

Given the above steps, I wanted to collect feedback on improving processing speed given the number of records, data size and the hardware I'm using. Ideas on improving performance and disk usage in any of the steps from 1 to 5 would be helpful. I could provide additional info needed. Also if there is some sort of standard process to investigate this, that would also be very helpful. If there are hardware related enhancements required - should I be looking at adding more memory, more RAM or something else ?

Also one of the anomalies I see in `pgAdmin` which I use to run the queries is that it reports query run time as a few minutes for each of the above operations where as in reality it runs for a number of hours.

**update**

As suggested by @filiprem , adding the schema and query operations below

```
-- db tables
my_db_201710=# \d
                         List of relations
 Schema |                  Name                  | Type  |  Owner
--------+----------------------------------------+-------+----------
 public | data_final                             | table | postgres   -- ~450 mill rows, ~50 GB
 public | data_distinct                          | table | postgres   -- ~450 mill rows, ~35 GB
 public | data_valid01                           | table | postgres   -- ~1.8 bill rows, ~200 GB
 public | data_raw01                             | table | postgres   -- ~2   bill rows, ~350 GB
 public | data_valid02                           | table | postgres   -- ~1.8 bill rows, ~200 GB
 public | data_raw02                             | table | postgres   -- ~2   bill rows, ~350 GB
 public | data_valid03                           | table | postgres   -- ~1.8 bill rows, ~200 GB
 public | data_raw03                             | table | postgres   -- ~2   bill rows, ~350 GB
 public | data_valid04                           | table | postgres   -- ~1.8 bill rows, ~200 GB
 public | data_raw04                             | table | postgres   -- ~2   bill rows, ~350 GB
(10 rows)

-- import csv data into postgres 
--------------
@echo off
setlocal
set PGPASSWORD=admin

for %%f in (*.csv)  do psql -d my_db_201710 -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 -c "\COPY public.data_raw01 FROM '%%~dpnxf' DELIMITER ',' CSV;"

pause
endlocal
--------------

my_db_201710=# \d+ data_raw01
                                          Table "public.data_raw01"
                 Column                  |       Type        | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------------------------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 type                                    | integer           |           | plain    |              |
 time                                    | bigint            |           | plain    |              |
 msg_type                                | integer           |           | plain    |              |
 si_id                                   | character varying |           | extended |              |
 mi_id                                   | character varying |           | extended |              |
 ti_id                                   | character varying |           | extended |              |
 session_id                              | character varying |           | extended |              |
 mip_address                             | character varying |           | extended |              |
 eip_address                             | character varying |           | extended |              |
 mm_id                                   | integer           |           | plain    |              |
 en_id                                   | integer           |           | plain    |              |

-- select valid records, columns with some column transformations
create table data_valid01 as (
    select report_data_time as epoch_time, mi_id, si_id,
        substring(lpad(substring(mi_id, 1,14 ), 14, '0'), 1,8 ) as mi_hdr,
        substring(lpad(substring(mi_id, 1,14 ), 14, '0'), 9,6 ) as mi_sn,
        substring(si_id, 1,5 ) as si_hdr,
        substring(si_id, 6,10 ) as si_sn,
        lpad(to_hex(mm_id),8,'0') as mmid, 
        lpad(to_hex(en_id), 6, '0') as enid
    from data_raw01
    where mi_id is not null and mm_id is not null and en_id is not null
    ) ;

my_db_201710=# \d+ data_valid01
                           Table "public.data_valid01"
   Column    |       Type        | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 epoch_time  | bigint            |           | plain    |              |
 si_id       | character varying |           | extended |              |
 mi_id       | character varying |           | extended |              |
 si_hdr      | text              |           | extended |              |
 si_sn       | text              |           | extended |              |
 mi_hdr      | text              |           | extended |              |
 mi_sn       | text              |           | extended |              |
 mmid        | text              |           | extended |              |
 enid        | text              |           | extended |              |

-- merge distinct from the 4 valid tables and select distinct rows from that
create table data_distinct as (
    select 
        distinct mmid, enid, si_hdr, si_sn, mm_hdr, mm_sn
        from (
            select *
                from data_valid01
                where epoch_time >= 1510202400000 and epoch_time <= 1510224000000
            union all
            select *
                from data_valid02
                where epoch_time >= 1510202400000 and epoch_time <= 1510224000000
            union all
            select *
                from data_valid03
                where epoch_time >= 1510202400000 and epoch_time <= 1510224000000
            union all
            select *
                from data_valid04
                where epoch_time >= 1510202400000 and epoch_time <= 1510224000000
            ) as a
);


my_db_201710=# \d+ data_distinct
         Table "public.data_distinct"
   Column    | Type | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------+------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 mmid        | text |           | extended |              |
 enid        | text |           | extended |              |
 si_hdr      | text |           | extended |              |
 si_sn       | text |           | extended |              |
 mi_hdr      | text |           | extended |              |
 mi_sn       | text |           | extended |              |

-- concatenate some cols, hash * concatenate some other colums 
create extension pgcrypto;
create table data_final as (
    SELECT id, simi
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, simi, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) cnt
        FROM
        (
            select
                mmid || ',' || enid as Id,
                si_hdr || encode(substring(digest(si_sn || 'Maria Sharapovan' , 'sha256') from 17), 'base64') || ',' ||
                    mi_hdr || encode(substring(digest(mi_sn || 'Maria Sharapovan' , 'sha256') from 17), 'base64') as simi
                from data_distinct
        ) t1
    ) t2
    where cnt = 1
); 

my_db_201710=# \d+ data_final
            Table "public.data_final"
  Column  | Type | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
----------+------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id       | text |           | extended |              |
 simi     | text |           | extended |              |


my_db_201710=#
```

Comment: You lost me at `on windows with billions of records`. I would try a different OS for starters. The Postgres community loves Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question but also very open one. I'm putting a list of recommendations here - hope it helps.

- Publish the full schema and data samples if you want more people work on this question.
- publish the postgresql.conf
- Follow the official PostgreSQL [Performance hints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/performance-tips.html).
- Use parallel processing when possible. On modern 4-core desktop CPU you can start with 2-3 threads. Observe system CPU usage (kernel time vs user time) while running the import. COPY is CPU-intensive.
- If you don't need durability and crash safety, follow [Non-Durable Settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/non-durability.html)
- Consider combining Step 2 and step 3 (filter on the fly) if you don't need the invaliid data in postgres.
- Consider plain UPDATE instead of copying the same data into new tables. It might be faster or slower depending on the structure/constraints.
- Before loading, remove all but absolutely required indexes. Recreate them after loading.
- Re hardware investments, purchasing SSD drive will have highest impact/cost ratio.

Comment: as suggested I have added the full schema and the queries here.

Comment: Thanks. 

It looks like not a single shot question but rather an optimization task which will take fair time to solve.

Try to track your I/O and CPU during the process - this would be very valuable input.